# Run Python Script on Web Server

Tags: python, web-services, cgi, server

I have a web server and my cgi-bin is on 0755, and my script called return.py is also 0755. And when my script is just this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

import cgi
import json


print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "testing...\n";
```

And I go to the web page I see testing... as I should, but when I add any of this to my script

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

param = form.getvalue("param")

if param:
    json.dumps({'success': True, 'message':  param })
else:
    json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':  'did not receive parameter' })
```

I get a 500 Internal Server Error, and Im not sure why, I have the correct permissions set, and the python is running because it works when I don't add the stuff above? Is there something wrong with my above code? What else could be causing this issue?

BY THE WAY the above code is because I am making a POST to this and what to return the value posted. Just a simple test case, but I can't get it to work?

Ive gone through this check list, of what I could check, and it all worked https://encodable.com/internal_server_error/

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

**EDIT**

here are error logs

```
[Tue Jun 23 01:35:38.661161 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 874653] [client 173.34------:51484] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/spencer/public_html/.htaccess
[Tue Jun 23 01:35:38.426745 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 874653] [client 173.34-----:51484] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/spencer/public_html/error_log
```

Comment: Check the log, there might be some error in code.

Comment: @Lafada not sure how to access or if I do have access to it? how can I find out?

Comment: @Lafada it says "client denied by server configuration: "

Comment: Please add your logs in question, that will help to understand your problem.

Comment: BTW, you do not print json results

Comment: And I don't understand why the code without json works, since you have a wrong shebang line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the shebang and it should work

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
import cgi
import json
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "testing...\n";
```

and assuming u save it as test.py works 
then u add below part

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
import cgi
import json
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "testing...\n";
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
param = form.getvalue("param")
if param:
    json.dumps({'success': True, 'message':  param })
else:
    json.dumps({'success': False, 'message':  'did not receive parameter' })
```

it gives server error

Then change the shebang to

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And it works .....put correct shebang and life is easy

Comment: Okay now it works, if I change it to `#!/usr/bin/python` but why? And I still need `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";` line above the all, why does that need to be there?